# Update value in hazelcast IMap which have MapStore without execute store to database

Tags: hazelcast

I'm using hazelcast for distributed cache on top of mysql. I have a map to store user info, with MapStore config, sometime user info in db changed by other reason not from my app, I want to update cache without update to database.
How can I do?

Comment: That is a good question. Let me see if I can get that information.

Comment: did you find out how to do it?  Can you use a trigger on the database that makes a call to a mysql user defined function from where you can update the hazelcast cache?

Comment: @alihaider: I manually manage what is cached in hazelcast and how to store into database, ignore MapStore.

Comment: @bachden - I thought you wanted to update hazelcast if DB info changed outside your app.Wondering if you can catch that change via trigger, tat trigger can call a user defined function in mysql, which can then connect to hazelcast and update the info there.  Perhaps I misunderstood something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `IMap.putTransient` to update entry without persisting to MapStore. Alternatively you can just evict the entry with `IMap.evict` and on next `get` it will be loaded form the MapStore.

Comment: Note that `putTransient` uses the 'hashCode and equals of the binary form of the key'.

This isn't a problem for simple keys, but I've just spent an afternoon banging my head on the screen because of a problem with a composite key that contained a `Collection` - the collection type was a `HashSet` which doesn't guarantee order, when I switched to an `ArrayList` it worked perfectly.